# filter array creating new array with title only

Tags: javascript

Using an array of objects:

```
[{... title:'sss'},
{... title:'esd'},
{... title:'ccc'},
{... title:'vvv'},
{... title:'bb'},
{... title:'ess'}]
```

I'd like to search elements and return an array containing only the title of each result, something like:

```
 const filtered = data.filter(function(el) {
                                return el.title === text;
                            }).map(title => title);
```

So if my search text was `es` I would end up with `['esd','ess']`

Comment: `.map(title => title);` should be `.map(title => title.title);`.

Comment: You could also use `.map(({title}) => title)`.

Comment: So you want partial search then use `data.filter(el => el.title.includes(text)).map(el => el.title)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there

```
const filtered = data.filter(el => el.title === text).map(el => el.title)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce` to execute only one iteration over the initial array, rather than two iterations (`filter` and `map`) for performance reasons:

```
const filtered = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (val.title === text)
        acc.push(val.title);        
    return acc;
}, []);
```

**NOTE**: 
There is no point of filtering against specific title and then returning an array of just the title. It is sure that **you are getting an array of the same text**.
Maybe, you could filter against another property, or include another property to the outputed array just to distinguish the resulting items.

You could also like to read about [transducers](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/transducers-efficient-data-processing-pipelines-in-javascript-7985330fe73d) that perform this task.

Answer (score 1):

As per this,

> So if my search text was `es` I would end up with `['esd','ess']`

You need [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes),

```
const filtered = data.filter(function(el) { return el.title.includes(text);}).map(el => el.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filtered = data.map(obj => obj.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
data.reduce((acc, { title }) => title.indexOf(text) > -1 ? (acc.push(title), acc) : acc, []);
```

**Demo:**

```js
const data = [{name: 'aa', title:'sss'},
{name: 'ee', title:'esd'},
{name: 'cc', title:'ccc'},
{name: 'vv', title:'vvv'},
{name: 'bb', title:'bb'},
{name: 'ss', title:'ess'}];

function filterData(data, text) {
   return data.reduce((acc, { title }) => title.indexOf(text) > -1 ? (acc.push(title), acc) : acc, []);
}

const filtered = filterData(data, 'es');

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to share something a bit different, here is an approach relying on a **single iteration** using **function generators**.

This method requires no filter and mapping, it just iterates the array, acceps a filter callback function and map callback function and yields the mapped function result if the filter function result is truthy.

```js
const data = 
[{name: 'aa', title:'sss'},
{name: 'ee', title:'esd'},
{name: 'cc', title:'ccc'},
{name: 'vv', title:'vvv'},
{name: 'bb', title:'bb'},
{name: 'ss', title:'ess'}
];

function* filterAndMap(arr, filterCallback, mapCallback) {
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (filterCallback(item)) yield mapCallback(item);
  }
}

const res = [...filterAndMap(data, ({title}) => title.indexOf('ss') > -1, ({title}) => title)];
console.log(res);
```